# Executing netstat from C# app returns "File Not Found" error

Tags: c#, command, system.diagnostics

I am trying to execute netstat command from my C# code and get "File Not Found" error.
Do I have to specify where "netstat.exe" is?

If so, how would I do it if (hypothetically) netstat and findstr are in two different folders?

```
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "netstat -a | findstr 5840";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    try
    {
        cmd.Start();
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
    StreamReader reader = cmd.StandardOutput;
    string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This is what fixed the problem:

```
// create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run and "/c " as the parameters.
// /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows and then exit.
string command = "netstat -a | findstr " + sTCPPort;
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =  new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
// Get the output into a string
result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the exact it is hard to know the exact issue, but it looks like you may need to cmd.exe and pass your command to it as an argument.

Comment: Yes, I did the same as you suggested before seeing your response and it worked. I have updated the question with the changes that fixed the issue. I marked your response as answer though.